# Can you expose azure table storage IQueryable ( table.CreateQuery() ) as POCO?

Tags: azure, repository, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have an large application with 30 plus projects that currently uses an IRepository and POCO entities. I would like to know if there is a way to use table storage without having to implement ITableEntity. I don't want to have to import the azure storage nugget packages into every project and change all my entities to use ITableEntity.

**Entity Adapater**

I am aware that it is possible to create an entity adapter (such as that below) which works quite well when reading or writing an individual entity. But I have not been able to get this to work when attempting to expose IQueryable via table.CreateQuery().

```
public class AzureEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string ETag { get; set; }
}

internal class AzureStorageEntityAdapter<T> : ITableEntity where T : AzureEntity, new()
{
    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the entity's partition key
    /// </summary>
    public string PartitionKey
    {
        get { return InnerObject.PartitionKey; }
        set { InnerObject.PartitionKey = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the entity's row key.
    /// </summary>
    public string RowKey
    {
        get { return InnerObject.RowKey; }
        set { InnerObject.RowKey = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the entity's Timestamp.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp
    {
        get { return InnerObject.Timestamp; }
        set { InnerObject.Timestamp = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the entity's current ETag.
    /// Set this value to '*' in order to blindly overwrite an entity as part of an update operation.
    /// </summary>
    public string ETag
    {
        get { return InnerObject.ETag; }
        set { InnerObject.ETag = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Place holder for the original entity
    /// </summary>
    public T InnerObject { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Ctor
    public AzureStorageEntityAdapter()
    {
        // If you would like to work with objects that do not have a default Ctor you can use (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        this.InnerObject = new T();
    }

    public AzureStorageEntityAdapter(T innerObject)
    {
        this.InnerObject = innerObject;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public virtual void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        TableEntity.ReadUserObject(this.InnerObject, properties, operationContext);
    }

    public virtual IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        return TableEntity.WriteUserObject(this.InnerObject, operationContext);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this...

```
public class TableStorageRepository : IRepository
{
    // snip...

    public IQueryable<T> FindAll<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        CloudTable table = GetCloudTable<T>();
        return table.CreateQuery<AzureStorageEntityAdapter<T>>();
    }

    // snip...
}
```

The problem here is the CreateQuery creates an

```
IQueryable<AzureStorageEntityApater<T>>.
```

I can't see how to get an IQueryable of all the 'InnerObjects'.

Does anybody know if it is possible to expose IQueryable by some means without exposting ITableEntity?

Comment: I've exactly the same problem nowadays with Azure Cosmos Table SDK. I Want to use CloudTable.CreateQuery<T> but T is constrained to ITableEntity and I wanted it to use my POCO object

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be what you want, but might give you some ideas.

I created a base repository and used a separate repository for each entity which is responsible for passing the correct CloudTable, partition/rowkey/property expressions and resolvers in.  I base it around DynamicTableEntity (which allows for some advanced stuff like dynamic properties in my entities (like small collections)).

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    protected async Task<DynamicTableEntity> GetAsync(CloudTable table, Expression<Func<DynamicTableEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        var query = table.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(filter).AsTableQuery();
        var segment = await query.ExecuteSegmentedAsync(null);
        return segment.Results.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    protected async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(CloudTable table, Expression<Func<DynamicTableEntity, bool>> filter, EntityResolver<T> resolver)
    {
        var query = table.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(filter).Resolve(resolver);
        var segment = await query.ExecuteSegmentedAsync(null);
        return segment.Results.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    protected async Task<IEnumerable<DynamicTableEntity>> GetAllAsync(CloudTable table, Expression<Func<DynamicTableEntity, bool>> filter, int take = 1000)
    {
        if (take > 10000) take = 10000;
        if (take < 1) take = 1;

        var query = table.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(filter).Take(take).AsTableQuery();
        var token = new TableContinuationToken();
        var results = new List<DynamicTableEntity>();
        while (token != null)
        {
            var segment = await query.ExecuteSegmentedAsync(token);
            results.AddRange(segment.Results);
            token = segment.ContinuationToken;
        }
        return results;
    }

    protected async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(CloudTable table, Expression<Func<DynamicTableEntity, bool>> filter, EntityResolver<T> resolver, int take = 1000)
    {
        if (take > 10000) take = 10000;
        if (take < 1) take = 1;

        var query = table.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(filter).Take(take).Resolve(resolver);
        var token = new TableContinuationToken();
        var results = new List<T>();
        while (token != null)
        {
            var segment = await query.ExecuteSegmentedAsync(token);
            results.AddRange(segment.Results);
            token = segment.ContinuationToken;
        }
        return results;
    }

    protected async Task<int> InsertAsync(CloudTable table, DynamicTableEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Insert(entity));
            return result.HttpStatusCode;
        }
        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            return ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 500;
        }
    }

    protected async Task<int> ReplaceAsync(CloudTable table, DynamicTableEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Replace(entity));
            return result.HttpStatusCode;
        }
        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            return ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 500;
        }
    }

    protected async Task<int> DeleteAsync(CloudTable table, DynamicTableEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Delete(entity));
            return result.HttpStatusCode;
        }
        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            return ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 500;
        }
    }

    protected async Task<int> MergeAsync(CloudTable table, DynamicTableEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Merge(entity));
            return result.HttpStatusCode;
        }
        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            return ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 500;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of a class inheriting from it (you'll have to use your imagination to fill in the blanks - let me know if you want to see a proper implementation)

```
// method
public Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(string pk1, string pk2, EntityResolver<T> resolver, int take = 1000, Expression<Func<DynamicTableEntity, bool>> filterExpr = null)
    {
        var keysExpr = x => x.PartitionKey.Equals(string.Format("{0}_{1}", pk1, pk2);
        var queryExpr = filterExpr != null ? keysExpr.AndAlso(filterExpr) : keysExpr;
        return base.GetAllAsync<T>(CloudTableSelector.GetTable(), queryExpr, resolver, take);
    }

// call
var products = await ProductRepo.GetAllAsync<ProductOwnerViewDto>(orgType, orgId, ProductOwnerViewDto.GetResolver(), take, x => x.RowKey.CompareTo(fromId) > 0);
```

It's a bit raw and a pain to wrap all your entities in separate repos, but I couldn't find a way to let me query the table in such a manner whilst letting me get different projections out (multiple resolvers per table).

I find solutions based on ITableEntity limiting (which is fine until you need dynamic properties then you're screwed).

Comment: Thanks for your input Peter. Not quite what I'm after but I appreciate your feedback nonetheless. 

I'm not looking to inject and wrap every entity in the system with its own repository and I am assuming exposing DynamicTableEntity also brings with it the azure storage library dependency? The point of decoupling ITable in the first place to use pure POCO's was to try and avoid this.

I haven't found a solution yet and I'm not sure one currently exists. But I will keep searching.. :)